# How to see #document-fragment in the Elements page in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to see all document fragments that were created on the page?
So far I am able to see them by using JS Debugger, adding DOM object to watch (or using console), and then using "Reveal in elements panel"
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/28/reveal-in-elements-panel?hl=en

But is there a way to go to straight to elements panel and see what are the document-fragments were created? 
Also tried this (worth a shot, right?):

```
document.getElementById("#document-fragment")
null
document.getElementById("document-fragment")
null
```

Comment: Not an answer but if you already have a the documentFragment and want to view it in the console put the fragment inside an array [fragment] and you'll see the contents of the fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a list of all document-fragments. They are not a part of the document tree so Elements panel doesn't show them. However, if you can find a reference to the document-fragment in some JS variable you can use console to reveal that fragment in the Elements panel:

```js
inspect(documentFragmentRef);
```

You can also find all document-fragments referenced in the JavaScript code of the inspected application by taking heap snapshot (Profiles panel > Take Heap Snapshot, Take Snapshot) and then filtering by DocumentFragment class name. After that select one of the fragments in the heap snapshot and it will be available in the console as $0 variable:

[image: DomcumentFragment selected in heap snapshot]